# How to add list of check boxes inside one div using html and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display the some list of check boxes inside one div using HTML and CSS. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Multiple Business Name :</span>
                //list of business names with check box         
    </div>
</div>
```

Here after the `span` i need to display the multiple labels with check boxes and if it will more after 6 the list will scroll. Please help me.

Comment: is checkboxes are dynamic or static?

Comment: it will be static.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8cc36h1t/

Comment: check above fiddle , is this what you want

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the scrolling behavior, insert your checkboxes into a `.container` div, give it a fixed `height` and set `overflow-y: scroll;`. This makes the container vertically scrollable if the content becomes greater than the container itself. See MDN for [more information about `overflow-y`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/overflow-y.html).

```css
.container {
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Multiple Business Name :</span>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 1
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 2
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 3
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 4
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 5
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 6
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 7
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 8
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 9
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 10
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @subhra does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/8cc36h1t/5/ ? You can accomplish it by adding a div after the span and wrapping it around the check boxes.

`.scroll {
    height: 160px;
    width: 167px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}`

```
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bnameList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Multiple Business Name :</span>
    <ul class="input-group-addon bnameList">
      <li>
        <label for="b1">business1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="b1"></li>
      <li>
        <label for="b2">business2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="b2"></li>
      <li>
        <label for="b3">business3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="b3"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

is this what you need?